# how 2 compare all properties of 2 JSON ,except one ,using UnderscoreJs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, underscore.js

I am using _.isFilter method of underscore js. It works perfectly if I want to check whether 2 JSONs are same or not. But I am facing one tiny problem.In One JS I have $$hashKey too as property, while in other It's not present. How can I compare 2 JSON's all properties except one i.e $$hashKey.

```
$rootScope.jsonOfHRA =  $scope.setFileNameAndOtherProperties($rootScope.jsonOfHRA);
globalJsonHRA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($rootScope.jsonOfHRA));

//This is how I make a deep copy of JSON

JSONOFHRA=
{
  "toShowVerified": 0,
  "sec10_decl_id": 390,
  "toShowEdit": 0,
  "toShowlineItemEditable": true,
  "edit": false,
  "sec10_decl_act_val": 0,
  "sec10_decl_other_text1": "asdsa",
  "sec10_decl_other_text2": "3434",
  "sec10_decl_other_text3": "adasda",
  "sec10_decl_decl_from_dt": "01/05/2014",
  "sec10_decl_status": 0,
  "sec10_decl_yr_end": "2015-03-31",
  "sec10_decl_yr_id": 2014,
  "listOfAttachments": [],
  "nameOfPayheadToShow": "HRA",
  "sec10_decl_proof": 0,
  "sec10_decl_ver_val": 0,
  "sec10_decl_yr_st": "2014-04-01",
  "sec10_decl_cust_id": 315,
  "add": false,
  "sec10_decl_curr_id": 0,
  "sec10_decl_mod_on": "2014-10-28 12:46:14.0",
  "sec10_decl_add_on": "2014-10-28 12:38:49.0",
  "sec10_decl_decl_to_dt": "30/06/2014",
  "sec10_decl_user_id": 32967,
  "sec10_decl_active": 0,
  "sec10_decl_decl_val": 1234,
  "sec10_decl_head_id": 3,
  "sec10_decl_decl_text": "Delhi",
  "$$hashKey": "19I"
}


GLOBALJSON = 
{
  "toShowVerified": 0,
  "sec10_decl_id": 390,
  "toShowEdit": 0,
  "toShowlineItemEditable": true,
  "edit": false,
  "sec10_decl_act_val": 0,
  "sec10_decl_other_text1": "asdsa",
  "sec10_decl_other_text2": "3434",
  "sec10_decl_other_text3": "adasda",
  "sec10_decl_decl_from_dt": "01/05/2014",
  "sec10_decl_status": 0,
  "sec10_decl_yr_end": "2015-03-31",
  "sec10_decl_yr_id": 2014,
  "listOfAttachments": [],
  "nameOfPayheadToShow": "HRA",
  "sec10_decl_proof": 0,
  "sec10_decl_ver_val": 0,
  "sec10_decl_yr_st": "2014-04-01",
  "sec10_decl_cust_id": 315,
  "add": false,
  "sec10_decl_curr_id": 0,
  "sec10_decl_mod_on": "2014-10-28 12:46:14.0",
  "sec10_decl_add_on": "2014-10-28 12:38:49.0",
  "sec10_decl_decl_to_dt": "30/06/2014",
  "sec10_decl_user_id": 32967,
  "sec10_decl_active": 0,
  "sec10_decl_decl_val": 1234,
  "sec10_decl_head_id": 3,
  "sec10_decl_decl_text": "Delhi"
}

//This is how I am comparing
if(_.isEqual(modifiedJson[i], GlobalUnmodifiedJson[j])){
                                        var idOfUnmodifiedLineItem = modifiedJson[i]["sec10_decl_id"];
                                        alert("Coming here in realm of unmodified of modifed");
                                        modifiedJson = _.filter(modifiedJson, function(item) {
                                            return item.id !== idOfUnmodifiedLineItem;
                                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `_.omit` function to take out the keys you don't want to compare before the `stringify`:

From the [underscore.js docs](http://underscorejs.org/#omit):

> **omit** `_.omit(object, *keys)`
>   Return a copy of the object, filtered to
>   omit the blacklisted keys (or array of keys). Alternatively accepts a
>   predicate indicating which keys to omit.

```
_.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}

_.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, function(value, key, object) {
    return _.isNumber(value);
});
=> {name: 'moe', userid: 'moe1'}
```

In your case, you could create objects from the JSON, `omit` the `$$hashKey` property, and then compare.